How does the induced current flow? From positive to negative or the opposite?
Let's say there's a rod and it in moving horizontally in a magnetic field (changing flux so current is induced). Using Fleming's right hand rule, we find that induced current flows from left to right. According to my book, this means the left is positive and the right is negative. But doesn't current usually flow from positive to negative?
And does emf have a direction? If so how do we find that?

This situation is easier to understand when you can see a circuit. In many examples like yours, involving a rod moving in a magnetic field, the circuit is completed by having the rod move along fixed rails, with some suitable load connecting the rails.
If the current inside the rod moves from left to right, then it must complete the circuit by moving from the right hand side of the rod through the rails and load back to the left hand side of the rod. This means the right hand side of the rod looks positive when seen from outside, so it is what we would call the positive end.
This rod is a bit like a battery with its positive end at the right hand side. If you connect it to something current flows from positive to negative outside the battery, but it flows from the negative terminal to the positive terminal inside the battery, driven by the chemical reactions.
In the situation where the rod is not connected we only have movement of charge inside the rod, and the charge moves from the left end to the right end making the right end the positive end. When the rod stops or the magnetic field ends the charge distributes itself back again.
The emf only acts within the rod. It is what pushes the charge to separate into positive (at the right) and negative (at the left). It pushes the current from the negative end of the rod through the rod to the positive end. Outside the rod there is no emf, so the current flows from positive to negative.

Thank you so much ! I finally understood this concept!! Thanks again
